# How to click several checkbox and a Drop-down using Selenium package in python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to select the checkboxes that are unchecked in this website: https://dataunodc.un.org/GSH_app
, in 'National Data'. Moreover, I would like to select '100' from the Drop-Down Menu ('Show...entries').

I am using selenium and python. Could you tell me how to do it?

This is a part of the HTML code corresponding to the checkbox selection:

```
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="YearVar" value="1990" checked="checked">
                      <span>1990</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="YearVar" value="1991">
                      <span>1991</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="YearVar" value="1992"
```

And this one corresponds to the  Drop-down menu:

```
 name="DataTables_Table_0_length" aria-
controls="DataTables_Table_0" class=""><option
 value="10">10</option><option
 value="25">25</option><option
 value="50">50</option><option 
 value="100">100</option></select> entries</label>
```

Comment: Do you have any code where you have tried to do this already? Post your attempts so people have something to build off and help you learn.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: linked site is under maintenance. Please post full html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the all checkbox which are not checked and click on those checkbox.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following `XPATH` option.Then iterate the elements and click each of them.

```
#Get all checkbox which are not selected.
allchekbox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='YearVar' and not(@checked='checked')]")))

for item in allchekbox:
    item.click()
```

> In order to select value for `dropdown` use selenium select `class`.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and `visibility_of_element_located`() and either of `Xpath` option.

> XPATH 1:

```
 # Select Item from dropdown
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[starts-with(@name,'DataTables_Table_')]")))
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_value("100")
```

Or

> XPATH 2:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[normalize-space(text())='Show']/select")))
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_value("100")
```

---

Here is the complete Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://dataunodc.un.org/GSH_app")
driver.maximize_window()

#Switch the iframe in order to access the link
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://unodc.shinyapps.io/GSH_App/']")))
#Click on National Data link
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="nav navbar-nav"]//a[text()="National Data"]'))).click()

#Get all checkbox which are not selected.
allchekbox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='YearVar' and not(@checked='checked')]")))

#iterate and click each checkbox
for item in allchekbox:
    item.click()

#To avoid StaleElementReferenceException add time.sleep()
time.sleep(2)
# Select Item from dropdown
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[starts-with(@name,'DataTables_Table_')]")))
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_value("100")
```